# simpleXmlIterator->valid() returns false for valid xml

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to use the simpleXmlIterator to iterate through the following xml. Which xmlspy and notepad++ claim are valid. The simplexmlelement->asXML() returns the same input. However simpleXmlIterator->valid() returns false even after simpleXmlIterator->rewind().

Why does the function simpleXmlIterator->valid() consider it invalid?
My php code which echos N

```
$xml = new simpleXmlIterator( $xmlstring );
$xml->rewind();
echo $xml->valid() ? "Y" : "N";
```

XML used in $xmlstring

```
<tns1:transaction xmlns:tns="http://www.cancerresearchuk.org/di/r17/commonTypes" xmlns:tns1="http://www.cancerresearchuk.org/di/r17/supplier/newdonate" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cancerresearchuk.org/di/r17/commonTypes commonTypesDI.xsd http://www.cancerresearchuk.org/di/r17/supplier/newdonate supplier_newdonate_Version4.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tns1:reference>DG007</tns1:reference>
  <tns1:supporter>
    <tns1:primaryExternalReferenceId>DeepsSceThree</tns1:primaryExternalReferenceId>
    <tns1:primaryDataSourceCode>ND</tns1:primaryDataSourceCode>
    <tns1:secondaryExternalReferenceId></tns1:secondaryExternalReferenceId>
    <tns1:secondaryDataSourceCode></tns1:secondaryDataSourceCode>
    <tns1:forename>TT</tns1:forename>
    <tns1:startDate>2014-07-15T13:11:20.000000000</tns1:startDate>
    <tns1:source>12XSU7006</tns1:source>
    <tns1:statusCode>Live</tns1:statusCode>
    <tns1:statusDate>2014-07-29</tns1:statusDate>
    <tns1:surname>GuptaSceThree</tns1:surname>
    <tns1:title>Sir</tns1:title>
    <tns1:address>
      <tns1:addressLine1>28 Cadmus Court</tns1:addressLine1>
      <tns1:addressLine2></tns1:addressLine2>
      <tns1:addressLine3></tns1:addressLine3>
      <tns1:city>London</tns1:city>
      <tns1:country>United Kingdom</tns1:country>
      <tns1:county>Cheshire</tns1:county>
      <tns1:postalCode>OX4 2WB</tns1:postalCode>
      <tns1:startDate>2014-01-13</tns1:startDate>
      <tns1:validationStatus>NV</tns1:validationStatus>
    </tns1:address>
    <tns1:contactInfo-Phone>
      <tns1:phoneNumber>01231231221</tns1:phoneNumber>
    </tns1:contactInfo-Phone>
    <tns1:contactInfo-Email>
      <tns1:emailAddress>james@johnson.com</tns1:emailAddress>  
    </tns1:contactInfo-Email> 
                <tns1:contactInfo-Mobile>
      <tns1:mobileNumber>07516655678</tns1:mobileNumber>
                </tns1:contactInfo-Mobile>
                <tns1:directDebit>
      <tns1:accountName>JessiAccName</tns1:accountName>
      <tns1:amount>20.12</tns1:amount>
      <tns1:bankAccountNumber>43608868</tns1:bankAccountNumber>
      <tns1:bankSortCode>050370</tns1:bankSortCode>
      <tns1:bankAccountCode-CRUK>121</tns1:bankAccountCode-CRUK>
      <tns1:frequency>Monthly</tns1:frequency>
      <tns1:product>CRDD</tns1:product>
      <tns1:reference>Deeps3</tns1:reference>
      <tns1:source>Donations</tns1:source>
      <tns1:paymentDay>19</tns1:paymentDay>
      <tns1:toBeGiftAided>Y</tns1:toBeGiftAided>
      <tns1:letterCodeGAD>09DTDVGC</tns1:letterCodeGAD>
      <tns1:methodGAD>Written</tns1:methodGAD>
      <tns1:inMemoryName>TOM</tns1:inMemoryName>
      <tns1:motivation>MEM</tns1:motivation>
      <tns1:dataSource>ND</tns1:dataSource>
    </tns1:directDebit>
    <tns1:listOfSuppressionsPreferences>
      <tns1:suppressionsPreferences>
        <tns1:startDate>2014-08-18</tns1:startDate>
     <tns1:suppressionPreferenceCode>SMS</tns1:suppressionPreferenceCode>
        <tns1:source>12XSU7009</tns1:source>
      </tns1:suppressionsPreferences>
    </tns1:listOfSuppressionsPreferences>
<tns1:listOfMailingActivities>
      <tns1:mailingActivities>
        <tns1:originatorActivityID>SK-ACT-OID0048</tns1:originatorActivityID>
        <tns1:category>Donate in Memory</tns1:category>
        <tns1:endDate>2014-08-20T21:21:01.000000000</tns1:endDate>
        <tns1:letterCode>1VGA</tns1:letterCode>
      </tns1:mailingActivities>
    </tns1:listOfMailingActivities>  
  </tns1:supporter>
</tns1:transaction>
```

The reason behind this is that I want to convert the XML to array/json and the standard solutions are not working because of namesapce. I found this code which claims to work but fails to get through the first hurdle of main while loop, so I assume it is my XML that is the problem. Here is the code I am using

```
    public function xmlToArray( $xml, $namespaces )
{
    $a = array();
    $xml->rewind();
    echo $xml->valid() ? "Y" : "N";
    while( $xml->valid() )
    {
        $key = $xml->key();
        if( !isset( $a[$key] ) ) 
        {
            $a[$key] = array(); $i=0; 
        }
        else
        {
            $i = count( $a[$key] );
        }
        $simple = true;
        foreach( $xml->current()->attributes() as $k=>$v ) 
        {
            $a[$key][$i][$k]=(string)$v;
            $simple = false;
        }

        if( $this->namespaces ) 
        {
            foreach( $this->namespaces as $nid=>$name ) 
            {
                foreach( $xml->current()->attributes( $name ) as $k=>$v ) 
                {
                    $a[$key][$i][$nid.':'.$k] =( string )$v;
                    $simple = false;
                }
            }
        } 
        if( $xml->hasChildren() ) 
        {
            if( $simple ) $a[$key][$i] = $this->xmlToArray( $xml->current(), $this->namespaces );
            else $a[$key][$i]['content'] = $this->xmlToArray( $xml->current(), $this->namespaces);
        } 
        else 
        {
            if($simple) 
            {
                $a[$key][$i] = strval( $xml->current() );
            }
            else 
            {
                $a[$key][$i]['content'] = strval( $xml->current() );
            }
        }
        $i++;
        $xml->next();
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Comment: The `valid()` method does not have anything to do with the XML. The method belongs to the `RecursiveIterator` interface, which is a way of making the object iteratable using `foreach`. You should show us your PHP code, so that we may see where the error may be coming from.

Comment: I have added the php code used

Comment: Okay, but why are you even calling these methods? Unless you are somehow changing the iterator there is no point to using them. I think you may be misunderstanding what the `valid()` method does. It does not have *anything* to do with the XML. PHP calls it, to check that the current index exists (that the index is valid), when you iterate over the object using `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks I have added some background and more code

Comment: Okay, I have mentioned this twice already. I am only going to say it one more time: **You should not use those methods**. You should use a `foreach` loop to iterate over the object, not a `while` loop.

Comment: Sorry, being a bit slow there, using foreach now as suggested. Thanks